# Bash Function is not getting called, unless I echo the return value

Tags: bash, shell

In my program I am trying to return a value from a function, the return value is string. Everything works fine(atleast some part), if I echo the value once it is returned, but it is not even calling the function, if I dont return.... Consider the code below....

```
#!/bin/bash

function get_last_name() {
    echo "Get Last Name"
    ipath=$1

    IFS='/'
    set $ipath
    for item
            do
                    last=$item
            done

    echo $last
}

main() {
    path='/var/lib/iscsi/ifaces/iface0'
    current=$(get_last_name "$path")
    echo -n "Current="
    echo $current
}


main
```

It gives me an output like this

```
OUTPUT
     Current=Get Last Name iface0
```

If I comment the echo $current, then the I am not even seeing the "Get Last Name", which makes to come to conclusion, that it is not even calling the function. Please let me know what mistake I am making. But one thing I am sure, bash is the ugliest language I have ever seen.......

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't just do `current="${path##*/}"`? That should strip everything up to and including the last `/`. Also your `for` loop is missing the `in` clause.

Comment: The reason is I know only C/C++ and I am not familiar with regular expression, I dont trust this inconsistent outputs by bash, so decided to write my own logic..... But if you think thats the way to do.... I will give a try..... Thanks a ton....

Comment: It's not regex, it's brace expansion (`man bash`)

Comment: Even if you don't know Bash's brace expansion, there's the external utility `basename`.

Comment: I guess, I will use that now...... I am just prototyping in this language(def, not my choice you see).... Will do this and better off soon.......

Comment: you should not modify IFS or unset it after for loop, also add an echo command at the end, because echo -n does not print the \n so your prompt overwrite the output

Comment: It's not brace expansion, it's [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). Brace expansion is an entirely different type of expansion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Functions do not have return values in bash. When you write

```
current=$(get_last_name "$path")
```

you are not assigning a return value to `current`. You are capturing the standard output of `get_last_name` (written using the `echo` command) and assigning it to `current`. That's why you don't see "Get last name"; that text does not make it to the terminal, but is stored in `current`.

---

### Detailed explanation

Let's walk through `get_last_name` first (with some slight modifications to simplify the explanation):

```
function get_last_name () {
    ipath=$1

    local IFS='/'
    set $ipath
    for item
    do
        last=$item
    done

    echo "Get Last Name"
    echo $last
}
```

I added the `local` command before `IFS` so that the change is confined to the body of `get_last_name`, and I moved the first `echo` to the end to emphasize the similarity between the two `echo` statements. When `get_last_name` is called, it processes its single argument (a string containing a file path), then echoes two strings: "Get Last Name" and the final component of the file path. If you were to run execute this function from the command line, it would appear something like this:

```
$ get_last_name /foo/bar/baz
Get Last Name
baz
```

The exit code of the function would be the exit code of the last command executed, in this case `echo $last`. This will be 0 as long as the write succeeds (which it almost certainly will).

Now, we look at the function `main`, which calls `get_last_name`:

```
main() {
    path='/var/lib/iscsi/ifaces/iface0'
    current=$(get_last_name "$path")
    echo -n "Current="
    echo $current
}
```

Just like with `get_last_name`, `main` will not have a return value; it will produce an exit code which is the exit code of `echo $current`. The function begins by calling `get_last_name` inside a command substitution (`$(...)`), which will capture all the standard output from `get_last_name` and treat it as a string.

**DIGRESSION**

Note the difference between the following:

```
current=$(get_last_name "$path")
```

sets the value of `current` to the accumulated standard output of `get_last_name`. (Among other things, newlines in the output are replaced with spaces, but the full explanation of how whitespace is handled is a topic for another day). This has nothing to do with return values; remember, the exit code (the closet thing `bash` has to "return values") is a single integer.

```
current=get_last_name "$path"
```

would not even call `get_last_name`. It would interpret "$path" as the name of a command and try to execute it. That command would have a variable `current` with the string value "get_last_name" in its environment.

The point being, `get_last_name` doesn't "return" anything that you can assign to a variable. It has an exit code, and it can write to standard output. The `$(...)` construct lets you capture that output as a string, which you can then (among other things) assign to a variable.

**Back to `main`**

Once the value of `current` is set to the output generated by `get_last_name`, we execute
two last `echo` statements to write to standard output again. The first writes "Current=" without a newline, so that the next `echo` statement produces text on the same line as the first. The second just echoes the value of `current`.

When you commented out the last `echo` of `main`, you didn't stop `get_last_name` from being executed (it had already been executed). Rather, you just didn't print the contents of the `current` variable, where the output of `get_last_name` was placed rather than on the terminal.

Comment: Not strictly true. They do have numeric return codes. If you don't `return`, it will return the exit code of the last executed command.

Comment: Those are exit codes. You can't get those directly from the function; you need to check `$?` as with other commands. The OP was confusing standard output with the idea of function return values that can form the RHS of an assignment statement.

Comment: You can get them directly in some contexts, for example `if function; then ...`. Just trying to clarify since the answer wasn't completely accurate.